# How to achieve modular Ant builds?

Tags: java, ant, build, modularity, properties-file

I would like to have a "modular" (reusable) Ant build that I can reuse across multiple projects. The build might be able to take a project (directory) name as input and run the same common targets on various projects' source code. This is to prevent having the same exact (or nearly exact) `build.properties` and `build.xml` files for each and every project.

So, given the following setup:

1. `build-base.properties` is a "base" props file, containing properties that will exist for all buildscripts
2. `build-1.xml` uses properties defined in `build-base.properties` as well as `build-1.properties`
3. `build-2.xml` uses properties defined in `build-base.properties` as well as `build-2.properties`
4. `build-3.xml` uses properties defined in `build-base.properties` as well as `build-3.properties`, **and uses targets defined in both `build-1.xml` and `build-2.xml`**

What would `build-3.xml` need to look like (basic structure) to import/use `build-base.properties` properties, and have access to `build-1.xml`/`build-2.xml` targets? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know to accomplish this type of modularity in Ant is to create an ant file to contain the common targets (call it `common-targets.xml` or whatever you like), and use the `import` task in the `build-[n].xml` property files.  If you have troubles with properties not sharing the way you like, you should also look at utilizing `macrodef`.